# Combine two contour plots with region function in one with common bar legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following two contour plots

```
kp = 1; km = 0.02;
rhomax = 0.5429908044496687`;
Jmax = (kp*
     rhomax*(1 - rhomax))/(((1 + kp)) - (kp/(kp + 1 - rhomax + km)));
kcap = km + kp;

alphaboundary = 0.41043749379435435`  ;
betaboundary = 0.345445461185593` ;
alphap = alpha*(1 - Jmax/beta)
rhoLD = (kp*(alphap + kcap) + (alphap + kp) - 
     Sqrt[(alphap*(kp + 1) + kp*(kcap + 1))^2 - 
       4*alphap*kp*(kcap + kp*kcap + 1)])/(2*kp);
JLD = (kp*
     rhoLD*(1 - rhoLD))/(((1 + kp)) - (kp/(kp + 1 - rhoLD + km)));
A1 = RegionPlot[{alpha*(1 - Jmax/beta) > alphaboundary && 
    beta > betaboundary}, {alpha, 0, 1}, {beta, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {alpha, beta}]
A2 = ContourPlot[rhomax, {alpha, 0, 1}, {beta, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{alpha, beta}, 
    alpha*(1 - Jmax/beta) > alphaboundary && beta > betaboundary && 
     alpha > alphaboundary], Contours -> {Automatic, 50}]
A3 = ContourPlot[rhoLD, {alpha, 0, 1}, {beta, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{alpha, beta}, alpha*(1 - Jmax/beta) <= alphaboundary], 
  Contours -> {Automatic, 50}, ColorFunction -> "Monochrome"]
```

I want to club A2 and A3 such that the bar legend is common. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The code you have uploaded has errors. Please include the undefined variables to present a minimal working example.

Comment: The code is working fine now.